# HTML button doesn't show pop-up

Tags: javascript, html

I have an HTML page that creates buttons from a list it gets from python code.

`list = ['a','b','c','d']` it will build buttos names a b c d, 4 buttons.

And I added a script `myFunction` that on-click gives a pop up to put some clear text that I send to my python code.
It all works for all buttons on the list, except for the last button and I don't know why.

only for the last button created in the page won't show pop-up and decides that the user entered an empty response on the clear text.

code:

```
<form target="_blank" method="get" action="connect" style="display: inline;">
        {% if thing['x'] %}
                <button class="button button" onclick="myFunction(form);openNav()"> {{ thing['letters'] }} </button>
                <input type="hidden" name="reason" id="myField" value=""/>
        {% endif %}
</form>    

function myFunction(frm) {
  var txt;
  console.log(frm.reason.value); // 1st option
  console.log(event.srcElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.outerHTML) // 2nd option
  var reason = prompt("Please enter reason:");
  if (reason == null || reason == "") {
    txt = "CANCEL";
  } else {
    txt = reason;
  }
  frm.reason.value = txt; // 1st option
  console.log(event.srcElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.value == txt); // 2nd option
  return txt
}
```

Error i see in F12:

```
Authentication:271 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'outerHTML' of null
    at myFunction (Authentication:271)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (Authentication:230)
```

I see it gives red X on this line : 
`console.log(event.srcElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.outerHTML) // 2nd option`

Comment: `onclick` can only contain one line of JavaScript code (*no semi-colons*).

Comment: Please edit into the question everything that appears in the console.

Comment: @Zera I added all i see there i hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to delete the consol log. this was what dropped everything for the last button.

```
  console.log(event.srcElement.parentElement.nextElementSibling.outerHTML) // 2nd option
```

As it got NULL response.